# Which container should I choose to implement a heap?

Tags: c++, containers, binary-heap

I am trying to make my own libraries in c++ and want to implement heap data structure.

I have *already coded all the algorithms* for the insert, delete and find for the heap

What I need is a container to hold the heap.

I know that they are implemented as arrays, but since arrays have to be a constant size and I don't like to reallocate memory too many times. Should i use `vector` as my container for heap?

I have implemented `vector` myself.

Comment: If your implementation is good and efficient. I don't see a reason not to.

Comment: have any idea what the stl in c++ uses to implement it....?

Comment: Not sure about internals.. But, you have std::make_heap functions in the algorithms library, and you can do make_heap on an stl vector. So it is definitely possible to create a heap from a vector in stl.

Comment: Please ask the following question: Can you guarantee the heap (min / max) properties ( eg.O(1) for min/max; reheap logn etc.) if you can its immaterial how & what are you doing inside.